# Make bigger screens (bigger resolutions) make you see more map in RTS games?

Tags: technical-issues, monitor

I have always wondered why bigger screen sizes/bigger resolutions don't make you see more of the map in RTS games (in any game, really, but this can be partially solved in FPS games by increasing FOV).

As far as I know, this happened in old games (for example, Sierra's old Pharaoh game works this way) but nowadays' games scale and make the game bigger, meaning playing at 1080p or at 1440p doesn't really alter the amount of things you see on screen.

Is there any workaround for this? I would like to adjust the game to make everything smaller while playing at 2560x1440, to see a bigger portion of the battlefield.

EDIT: I already know the difference between the concepts of **resolution** and **screen size**. I use them indistinctly because as the monitor gets bigger the resolution *usually* goes up to mantain the ppi.

EDIT2: I didn't know this was game dependant, that's what I was asking for. I was asking **IF** there was a way to do it.

Comment: Workarounds depend entirely on the game itself.  There's no way to provide an answer that will work for every single game.  If you have a specific game, I'd recommend focusing on that game alone.

Comment: It depends entirely on the game and how it's coded to handle different resolutions. For most MOBAs, I'd suspect that they would be coded in such a way that higher resolutions don't get any advantage over other players who might not be able to afford an HD monitor. For other games (Terraria for example), a high resolution will show more of the map around you. Since it depends so heavily on which game you're talking about, this question (as written right now) is too broad IMO.

Comment: I don't think this question is too broad, because it doesn't seem to be asking for individual answers for each and every RTS game.  It may be better suited to the game dev SE (as they should have the expertise to detail why you are seeing things as they are).

Comment: As Frank suggests, if you have a problem with a specific game, it may be better to ask for that game alone.  There may be some config amendment, mod or other way to get the desired outcome you seek.

Comment: Short of rewriting the code of the game there's no way to force a game to display more than what the developers chose to display. In specific cases the developers might have created secret configuration options or some third party might have created a patch, but in general there's no way you can force a game to display more of the battlefield. (I'd also note that games have no idea what the physical size of your screen is. There's no good way of determining whether you're using a 11" laptop screen, a 23" monitor, or a 60" TV.)

Comment: Of course this is game dependent; how could it not be?  Do you have a specific game you're having a resolution issue with?  If not, I'm afraid this question is probably going to stay closed.

Comment: 3d games are abstracted from away from raw pixel sizes and focus on a viewport (or "viewing frustum"). When you change the resolution, this viewport does not get farther away from the scene. Your game would need to allow for the camera (read: you) to move backwards from the scene. In some 3d games (RTS/GOD-like), this is OK, but in and shooter, this simply means you are moving backwards.

Answer (score 2):

You may be confusing two different concepts.

Resolution is where we see game video scaled to the screen.  All of the same content is on display, but the game video is stretched to best fit the screen.  You will find game engines are designed to use APIs (such as DirectX) to scale as desired.  This helps a game support any game screen (i.e. without a dependency on a limited number of sizes in such a wide range of available screen sizes).  This forms part of the rendering stage for (most) games.

Over time this may naturally support bigger screens through scaling, or perhaps needs some mod to intercept/realign API function calls (for cases where the game purposely limited its resolution to a selection of resolutions).

As for getting more items to fit on screen, this is more entwined into the game engine itself.  You are not going to find an easy or universal method that will allow screens to show more of the game world depending on some controllable variable.

Each game will have its own "model" of the game world.  This model will be optimised so that hardware at the time of its release can run smoothly.  Unless the developer makes regular patches in this area, you are very unlikely going to see "more" items on screen if you use a large screen/resolution (beyond any optimisation that may be built in during the initial release).  You may find a mod that somehow manages to tweak variables in the executable or a data file, but in most cases you are just stuck with the game as is.

Also, there is a somewhat unfair advantage if one player sees less of the map to another because they possess a smaller monitor.  This probably only affects online play, but still, why make the game behave so differently?

For these reasons, you are more likely to see a game possess visual scaling properties as opposed to seeing more items on screen for larger screens.